# changed behaviour in I2C LCD

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, lcd

I reinstalled a previously working sketch to my UNO and now the behaviour of the lcd has changed.

Previously this example worked perfectly:

```
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);  // set the LCD address to 0x27 for a 16 chars and 2 line display

void setup()
{
  lcd.init();                      // initialize the lcd 

  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.print("Hello, world!");
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Now it only displays the very first character 'H'

This version does work though:

```
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);  // set the LCD address to 0x27 for a 16 chars and 2 line display

void setup()
{
  lcd.init();                      // initialize the lcd 

  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.print("H");
  lcd.print("e");
  lcd.print("l");
  lcd.print("l");
  lcd.print("o");
  lcd.print(" ");
  lcd.print("W");
  lcd.print("o");
  lcd.print("r");
  lcd.print("l");
  lcd.print("d");  
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Can anyone shed me any light what is the reason of this change in behaviour and how to solve it?

Running version 1.8.3 on a W7pro PC

Comment: Where does it print the letter H, at position 0, 0? If not, try lcd.home(); right after lcd.backlight();.

Comment: ok thanks, I tried that but the result is exactly the same

Comment: I've tried both of your sketches and they work fine. What happens if you remove the "!" character from your first sketch?

Comment: Removing the '!' gives the same problem, I also tried removing the ',' without any improvement..

Comment: Have you updated your IDE to a newer version or the LiquidCrystal_I2C library recently?

Comment: Yes the IDE was updated pretty recently (v1.8.3), the library is the same as before (LiquidCrystal_I2C1602V1).

Comment: ok got it, see my answer, thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an incompatibility between recent versions of the IDE and the library I was using.

Installing the latest version of the library from GitHub and replacing the `lcd.init()` command with `lcd.begin()` in my sketches solved the problem.

Comment: Accept your own answer to close this question.

Comment: sorry, can't accept yet, I have to wait till tomorrow